# Ajax search - load all data on page load

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax search form that contains only checkboxes.

I want to be able to load all the results when the page load.

I tried to check that if all the checkboxes are unchecked then the first if in the `fetchResults` function will execute

what happens now is that I see all the results on page load but when I click the checkboxes, the results do not change.

kind'a lost. 
any help would be amazing.

I tried this thing

**this is the form:**

```
 <form method="get" class="searchform" id="dealssearchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );?>">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 search-col">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="downloadspeed" value="100MB" class="cb" />
                            100MB
                        </label>
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="downloadspeed" value="200MB" class="cb"/>
                            200MB
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 search-col">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="uploadspeed" value="100MB" class="cb" />
                            100MB
                        </label>
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="uploadspeed" value="200MB" class="cb"/>
                            200MB
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 search-col">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="199" class="cb" />
                            199 ש"ח
                        </label>
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="65" class="cb"/>
                            65 ש"ח
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 search-col">
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="company_text" value="hot" class="cb" />
                            Hot
                        </label>
                        <label>

                            <input type="checkbox" name="company_text" value="בזק בינלאומי" class="cb"/>
                            בזק בינלאומי
                        </label>


                    </div>
                </div>

                    <div id="datafetch">

                    </div>      
                </form>
```

**this is the jquery event**

```
jQuery(".cb").on( "load click", fetchResults());
```

**this is the ajax function:**

```
  function ajax_fetch() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetchResults(){

    console.log('aa', jQuery('input.cb').not(':checked').length > 0)
    if(jQuery('input.cb').not(':checked').length > 0){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            type: 'post',
            data: { action: 'data_fetch'},
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
                // console.log(data);
                // console.log(choices);
            }
        });
    }else{

        // declaring an array
        var choices = {};

        jQuery('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
                if (!choices.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) 
                    choices[this.name] = [this.value];
                else 
                    choices[this.name].push(this.value);
            });



        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            type: 'post',
            data: { action: 'data_fetch', 'choices' : choices  },
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
                // console.log(data);
                // console.log(choices);
            }
        });


    };
};
</script>

<?php
};
```

Comment: tried with `jQuery(".cb").on( "load change", fetchResults());` as well but no results

Comment: If I understand you correctly it should be different handlers `jQuery(".cb").on('change', fetchResults)` and `jQuery(document).ready(fetchResults)`

Comment: @MoshFeu Thanks. the correc tanswer is
`jQuery(".cb").on( "change", fetchResults);
jQuery(document).ready(fetchResults);
`

as you mentioned.

Comment: Glad to hear :)